# How to print original string from Unicode string(such as \uD14C\uC2A4\uD2B8) in python

Tags: python, string, unicode

I searched a bit about this. But most of people want to convert original string(테스트) to unicode(\uD14C\uC2A4\uD2B8).

But **what I want is converting unicode string(such as \uD14C\uC2A4\uD2B8) to real string(테스트)**. I have JSON file in which all the Korean strings are in form of unicode(\uXXXX) and I have to parse it into original string. How can I do it in Python?

To sum up,

the way to convert unicode string to original string such as in Python
\uD14C\uC2A4\uD2B8 -> 테스트

Comment: it just prints everything like \uD14C\uC2A4\uD2B8. by the way, I'm using Python 3.5.1

Comment: file. it is 5Gb big data json. Loading data is not problem. I already loaded JSON file as stream but its contents is fully unicode escaped string. Thanks for your interest by the way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved by this way

1. read byte by byte and add byte(variable c) into variable
   aJSON+=encode(c)
2. aJSON.decode('unicode-escape') gives expected result.

Thanks for interest anyway..

Answer (score 0):

```
import codecs

file_variable = 'path/to/file.json'
with codecs.open(file_variable, encoding='utf-8') as file:
   json_object = json.load(file)
```

See if that allows you to handle your json in unicode. The import codecs also allows you to use the .encode() and .decode() functions to go back and forth between unicode and unicode escaped:

```
string = ((some unicode text here))
string.decode('utf-8')
string.encode('utf-8')
```